# How Can I Concatenate Column A and Column B into Column C in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column A has first name.  Column B has last name.  I need column C to be "display name" (first name and last name separated by a space).  I assume this involves the concatenate function.

Bonus Question:
Column D is email address.  I need column E to be "username" (everything in email address left of the @ symbol).  I assume this involves some regular expression function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part, yes you need CONCATENATE, for example:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, " ", B1)
```

For the second, something like:

```
=MID(D1,1,FIND("@",D1)-1)
```

will give you everything up to the @ of an e-mail address.

Comment: Yeah, the part I couldn't figure out was to copy the formula down to all of the cells in the column. A shortcut method for doing this is to double-click the fill handle while cell C2 is selected. The fill handle is the darker square dot in the lower right corner of the cell pointer. Source: http://www.mrexcel.com/tip074.shtml

Comment: Any idea on the second formula?

Comment: Just updated the answer for the 2nd part

Answer (score 2):

Since variety spices life, here are some other options.  Note that the ampersand "&" is the concatenation operator.

[image]