# Concatenation on 100's columns - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

I need to concatenate hundreds of columns, in excel. I've seen I can use `CONCATENATE(A1,B1)` 
as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/514319/how-can-i-concatenate-column-a-and-column-b-into-column-c-in-excel) but this isn't really practically for concatenating 100 columns.

Can this be done simply with excel?

I'm using office 365 for Mac.

Comment: If you can use another program, I would suggest copy/pasting everything to a text editor, replace on tabs (`\t` or copy paste a tab in the find part) and replace by nothing.

Comment: Well =concatenate(A1:A12) does not work...figured feeding it a range would suffice...it does not.

Comment: Save it as CSV. That should give you concatenated text. Do find and replace on tabs or spaces or whatever your delimiter is and then copy it back to excel.

Comment: CONCATENATE() can have up to 255 parameters. Tedious but not difficult to create the list of columns to use for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seemed like one of those little challenges that just needed to be figured out.

So I googled it...found this:

1. Pick a cell and make it a sum of the intended range.  In this example I want to concatenate A1 - A12
2. So in the selected cell type `=(A1:A12) [I had to use =TRANSPOSE(A1:A12)]` DO NOT PUSH ENTER.  The TRANSPOSE formula replaced the ;'s with ,'s when I executed the next step.
3. With the range typed out press F9, that will give you this  (Again dont hit enter): `={"bob","is","a","super","secret","duper","agent","man","from ","the ","planet ","ultron"}`
4. Click on the formula text area and replace the '{}' with parentheses and add concatenate to the front so it looks like this:  `=CONCATENATE("bob","is","a","super","secret","duper","agent","man","from ","the ","planet ","ultron")`

Credit to:  [GDH](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/02/09/concatenate-a-cell-range-without-vba-in-excel/)